# Is it possible to use Espresso to test app with AndroidForWork work profile

Tags: android, ui-automation, android-espresso, android-for-work

I want to test MyApp by Espresso. MyApp can do AndroidForWork enrollment. After enrollment there will be 2 MyApps on device: one is with personal profile and the other is with work profile like below: (I just use Download app as an example.)
[app with personal profile and work profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IKiQu.png)

[image]

**My question: Is it possible to use espresso to test both personal and work profile apps? If yes how to do it?**

What I want to test:

1. Launch MyApp (with personal profile, don't have work profile for MyApp yet). -- Espresso works fine.
2. Do AndroidForWork enrollment -- Espresso works fine, then MyApp with work profile is generated.
3. Launch MyApp with work profile and test it. -- **I don't know how to do it. My Espresso only launched MyApp with personal profile.** Both MyApps (with personal or work profile) have exact same package name.

BTW, I tried UIAutomator to test MyApp with work profile but MyApp has some webpage and UIAutomator cannot recognize web elements within it. That's why I still want to use Espresso to test MyApp with work profile.

Comment: Have you tried either using a custom test rule to switch to the profile before launching MyApp or combining espresso with UIAutomator so ActivityTestRule launchActivity is set to false, allowing UIAutomator to switch profile before launch?

Comment: How to switch to the work profile by custom test rule? Or how to use UIAutomator to switch profile? I tried to open MyApp with work profile manually, Espresso cannot recognize any UI on MyApp with work profile.

Answer (score 0):

Some possible options could be ([blocking activity launch](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/rule/ActivityTestRule.html#ActivityTestRule(java.lang.Class%3CT%3E,%20boolean,%20boolean))) :

**Use InstrumentationRegistry to launch intent targetting the profile**:

`InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().getUiAutomation().executeShellCommand("am start --user <USER_ID> -n <appId>/<activity>")`

(Fetching UserInfo with `pm list users` for instance)

**Use UIAutomator to launch target app:**

```
String appDrawer = "Apps";
String appTitle = "<App title>";

UiDevice device = UiDevice.getInstance(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation());
device.pressHome();

if (device.hasObject(By.descStartsWith(appDrawer))) {
    device.findObject(By.descStartsWith(appDrawer)).click();
}

UiScrollable apps = new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollable(true));
apps.scrollForward();
apps.scrollTextIntoView(appTitle);
List<UiObject2> items = device.findObjects(By.text(appTitle));

//TODO validate items content and identify the correct index
items.get(index).click();
```

Comment: I tried "Use InstrumentationRegistry to launch intent targeting the profile" and MyApp with work profile is launched. But Espresso still cannot recognize the UI on it. But if I use the same way to launch MyApp with personal profile Espresso can recognize the UI. I still cannot use Espresso to test MyApp with work profile. It seems Espresso always attach to app with personal profile.

Comment: Then, regarding your premise `UIAutomator cannot recognize web elements within it.` isn't any element accessible on that screen? Isn't anything displayed through uiautomatorviewer? If so, I'd recommend exploring UIAutomator validation again.

Comment: The lowest(leaf) level of what uiautomatorviewer displayed is android.webkit.WebView. The textbox and button I need to access are in that webview which are not displayed by uiautomatorviewer.

Comment: Do you have setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled active on your webview? which is the sdk version you're testing against?

Comment: yes, setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled is active and sdk version is 24.